# Excessive use of the Stack

Tags: stack, computer-science

This is really a theoretical question. My example will use C but the language isn't that important.

Let's say I create lots and lots of variables on the stack

```
int x0 = 0;
int x1 = 1;
.
.
.
int x100 = 100;
```

Now I want to call x0. Since the stack is LIFO, where are x100,...,x1 stored, temporarily, while x0 is being fetched? By this I mean, won't they have to be placed on registers? And if so, there simply aren't enough registers. Using the standard analogy of cafeteria trays, If I'm trying to get to the bottom tray, I need lots of people to hold onto the other trays while I get it, unless there are three stacks and I can do some "tower of hanoi" solution...

Obviously this question shows my ignorance of the stack and how it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the stack in a C program *behaves* like a stack when it comes to growing and shrinking, but not accessing: you can directly access all elements, regardless of how "deep" they are in the stack. I suggest you look at the assembly.

Comment: Note: In C, just because you create a local variable, doesn't mean that the local variable goes on the stack.  It could go in a register, it could go on the stack, it could get moved around, and it might go nowhere at all (it might be eliminated).  If you look at assembly for your code, I suspect all of the variables will be eliminated.

Comment: @ Cicada. I see, so the stack grows by LIFO, but access is direct. Makes sense.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp : If the variables are eliminated and I want to call them later in that code block what will happen? Or do you mean the compiler eliminates them if they aren't used?

Comment: @JJG: The compiler can eliminate them even if they are used, as long as the function gets the same result.  For example, `int func(void) { int x = 2, y = 3; y *= 2; return x + y }` will probably get optimized to `int func(void) { return 8; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top of the stack is simply a memory address so you can access it with an offset. That said, this would make your code extremely fragile.

The whole point of LIFO, is the last value you put on there is the next one you need, so in your example you'd either push them in reverse order, or you'd define a structure with them all in there and push it's address on to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a stack in that level of granularity.

The stack stores *stack frames*. Each stack frame stores a set of local variables, which of course can be accessed in constant time (by an offset relative to the stack pointer).